# Making an element overflow outside parent element

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using Material Design Lite to create cards.
I added a menu to the card but the content of the menu only appears within the card.
I want it to overflow like in this example (http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section)

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brizzz_/te5Lpw8m/

```
<div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button id="more_reddit" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                </button>
                 <ul id="more-reddit-menu" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
                  for="more_reddit">
                <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
                <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
                <li class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
                <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
                <li class="mdl-menu__item">Even Another Action</li>
              </ul>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.mdl-card` CSS rule has `overflow: hidden;` set.

I'm not sure if this is intentional, but removing that will achieve what you're looking for. If you must have `overflow: hidden;` on that element, you'll need to devise another solution. Like placing the menu outside that container and positioning it absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add overflow into stylesheet?